# NSGradient created with initWithColorsAndLocations: does not draw

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, nsimage

I created a gradient like this:

```
NSGradient *g = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithColorsAndLocations:
                 [NSColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1], 0,
                 [NSColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0], 1, nil];
```

But when I draw it into an image using `drawInRect:angle:`, I get a plain white image instead of a gradient. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `-initWithColorsAndLocations:` is a variadic function, the compiler doesn't know what types the arguments need to be (beyond the first argument). The callee requires that the "locations" be `CGFloat` values, but when `1` or `0` is passed, it's passed as an int, so it gets interpreted as a very small floating-point value.

The solution is to pass `(CGFloat)0.0` and `(CGFloat)1.0` for the locations instead of `0` and `1`.